# Does $L^{1}$ convergence implies almost everywhere cesaro convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $\mu$ a Borel measure and $f_{n} \in L^{1}(X,\mu)$  continuous functions such that $f_{n}(x) \overset {L^{1}} \rightarrow 0 $.
Now can we deduce that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(x) \overset{a.e} \rightarrow 0?$
what about for the general case when $f_{n}$'s are not assumed to be continuous?

Comment: You'll want $\int |f_n| \to 0$ else you can trivially create a counter example.

Comment: Sorry,you are right.I just edited it.